# How to get a set of values from a list so that the order of the set is such that the order in the list is still preserved in the set?

Tags: python, list, set

The list in my actual code is too large.
Is there a way to get the desired output.
An efficient way will be preferred.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
def function():
    listt=["the","cat","sat","on","the","mat","which","is","on","the","floor"]
    print (sorted(set(listt)))
function()

Output:['cat', 'floor', 'is', 'mat', 'on', 'sat', 'the', 'which']
Expected Output:["the","cat","sat","on","mat","which","is","floor"]
```

Comment: sets are not supposed to preserve order

Comment: how can i get my desired output?

Comment: Nicest way imo is `from  more_itertools import unique_everseen` `list(unique_everseen(items))`